# Can a constexpr c-string used as template parameter be instantiated in a template function?

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, language-lawyer

I have been prototyping a library in which I would like to use a c-string value defined locally in a function as a non-type template parameter.

In essence, the bare minimum implementation is the following (see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dKe1c5)):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

template <char const* C>
class compile_string {};

template <typename T>
auto foo() {
    static constexpr char const CSTR[] = "Hello, World!";

    return compile_string<CSTR>{};
}

int main() {
    auto shorty = foo<short>();
    auto inty = foo<int>();

    return std::is_same_v<decltype(shorty), decltype(inty)>;
}
```

When compiling this short program with the latest clang (11.0), in O1 to O3 everything works well, however when compiling with O0, linking fails.

Despite the assembly section containing:

```
; foo<short>()::CSTR
_ZZ3fooIsEDavE4CSTR:
        .asciz  "Hello, World!"

; foo<int>()::CSTR
_ZZ3fooIiEDavE4CSTR:
        .asciz  "Hello, World!"
```

There is a linker error:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
/tmp/example-a4bb3b.o:(.debug_info+0x1be): undefined reference to `foo()::CSTR'
```

Passing `-Xlinker --no-demangle` this error becomes:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
/tmp/example-35000b.o:(.debug_info+0x1be): undefined reference to `_ZZ3foovE4CSTR'
```

Where one realizes that somehow the template parameter of `foo` was stripped.

Notes:

- Gcc (7.3 and 10.2) successfully compiles this example.
- There is no reference to `_ZZ3foovE4CSTR` in the assembly -- nor to the other 2 variants, truth to be told -- which is probably why enabling optimizations "solve" the problem.

---

**Is the above program conforming to the C++17 standard?**

(And therefore am I observing an issue with the Clang compiler?)

*Bonus question: and is there a work-around, to side-step the issue?*

Comment: I think this line is kind of weird: "`/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld`" <-- it's supposed to be clang 11.0 right?

Comment: @JHBonarius: I found it a bit strange as well; especially as I was switching between gcc 10.2 and clang 11.0. Then again, this may just be the link to the platform linker in this case?

Comment: Hmm, the AST seems to be correct, but the IR shows a weird line `@_ZZ3foovE4CSTR = external dso_local constant [14 x i8], align 1`. Starting to smell like an issue. I guess you need to define the CSTR in the func templ right? Taking it out of there also fixes the issue. The issue seems to be caused by the return argument. You can make a second CSTR (e.g. CSTR2) and switching the templ. param for the return type changes the generated external symbol.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Yes, the goal is to create a macro usable in any function/lambda, therefore the string & instantiation need to occur in this specific context. I am not sure that I get the trick with CSTR2, do you have a godbolt link to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Hmm, I was wrong. [But here's the code](https://godbolt.org/z/Wb4hnY)